# What was filebuf::openprot intended for, and does it have a replacement?

Tags: c++

I'm in the middle of fixing some rather old C++ code that used the old-style iostream library, and I came across the following non-compiling lines of code:

```
::ofstream ofile;
ofile.open("filename", ios::trunc, filebuf::openprot);
```

I get this error:

```
error C2039: 'openprot' : is not a member of 'std::basic_filebuf<_Elem,_Traits>'
```

So obviously it's something that's not around any more. The problem is, I can't find any information on what `openprot` did as a parameter, and I therefore can't replace it with something new, and I'm afraid to remove the parameter altogether.

Anyone with any historical C++ knowledge know what this thing did?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That parameter indicates/indicated the protection mode to open the file with. It shows up in this [IBM Legacy Class Library Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp111.aix.doc%2Flegacy%2Fcbccl10032.html).

`filebuf::openprot` is/was the default argument to the `fstream` class family constructors and `open` functions' `prot` parameter, which indicates what protection mode the file should be opened/created with.

> The default protection mode used when opening files.

For example, on your system it might be `0644`, meaning that *if the file is created*, the owner will have read/write permissions, and everyone else will have read-only.

Seeing as in your case the default argument was being passed in anyway, I would say that it's safe to just remove.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I removed the parameter.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the Visual Studio 6.0 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243815%28v=VS.60%29.aspx), `openprot` uses the operating system's default:

> The file protection specification; defaults to the static integer `filebuf::openprot`, which is equivalent to the operating system default (`filebuf::sh_compat` for MS-DOS).